# How To Unset $_SESSION per row?

Tags: php, session

I have a table for showing SESSION data per row like this:

[image]

Here's the code for showing the SESSION:

```
$keys = array_keys($_SESSION['name']);
        $no=1;
        for($k=0; $k < count($keys); $k++) {
        $key = $keys[$k];
        $value = $array[$key];
        echo "<tr align='center'>
        <td>$no.</td>
        <td width='20%'>
            <input type='checkbox' name='cek[]' class='check1' value='".$_SESSION['jml_harga'][$key]."' style='display:none;'>
            <input type='text' class='txtField' name='".$_SESSION['name'][$key]."' value='".$_SESSION['name'][$key]."' readonly='true'>
        </td>
        <td width='16%'>
            <input type='text' class='txtField' name='".$_SESSION['jenis'][$key]."' value='".$_SESSION['jenis'][$key]."' readonly='true'>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type='text' class='txtField' name='".$_SESSION['merk'][$key]."' value='".$_SESSION['merk'][$key]."' readonly='true'>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type='text' class='txtField' name='".$_SESSION['katalog'][$key]."' value='".$_SESSION['katalog'][$key]."' readonly='true'>
        </td>
        <td width='7%'>
            <input type='text' class='txtField' name='".$_SESSION['jml_kebutuhan'][$key]."' value='".$_SESSION['jml_kebutuhan'][$key]."' style='text-align:center;' readonly='true'>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type='text' class='txtField' name='".$_SESSION['hps'][$key]."' value='".$_SESSION['hps'][$key]."' style='text-align:right;' readonly='true'>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type='text' class='txtField' id='hargas' name='".$_SESSION['jml_harga'][$key]."' value='".number_format($_SESSION['jml_harga'][$key],0,',','.')."' style='text-align:right;' readonly='true'>
        </td>
        </tr>";
        $no++;}
```

I want to make an option to unset the SESSION per row, like this:

[image]

So if I click the "Delete" in the first row, 
only the first row are unsetted while the second rows does not.

But I don't know how to unset it per row, if I use this code:

```
    unset($_SESSION['name']);
    unset($_SESSION['jenis']);
    unset($_SESSION['merk']);
    unset($_SESSION['katalog']);
    unset($_SESSION['kemasan']);
    unset($_SESSION['satuan']);
    unset($_SESSION['satuanbsr']);
    unset($_SESSION['kebutuhan']);
    unset($_SESSION['jml_kebutuhan']);
    unset($_SESSION['hps']);
    unset($_SESSION['jml_harga']);
```

It will unset the SESSION in all row. So, i hope someone can help me with this matter, Thank You.

Comment: Read up on [session_destroy()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-destroy.php), it will remove all you sessions...

Comment: well, i remove the session_destroy(), but it still remove all row session.

Comment: That's because you are not unsetting the correct KEY...

Comment: Yes you're right just like @SKRocks answer, my question already answered, thank you so much for spend some time, sir. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the key in delete link

like

```
<a href="delete.php?key=<?php echo $key;?>">Delete</a>
```

Now access your key in `delete.php` and remove session for that particular key

also remove `session_destroy` because it will remove all sessions

```
$key = $_GET['key'];

    unset($_SESSION['name'][$key]);
    unset($_SESSION['jenis'][$key]);
    unset($_SESSION['merk'][$key]);
    unset($_SESSION['katalog'][$key]);
    unset($_SESSION['kemasan'][$key]);
    unset($_SESSION['satuan'][$key]);
    unset($_SESSION['satuanbsr'][$key]);
    unset($_SESSION['kebutuhan'][$key]);
    unset($_SESSION['jml_kebutuhan'][$key]);
    unset($_SESSION['hps'][$key]);
    unset($_SESSION['jml_harga'][$key]);
```

Comment: thank you sir, it's working, but i need to add the session_start() first, thank you so much.. :)

Answer (score 2):

Remove `session_destroy();` line since it removes whole session. 
To remove only part of it, just `unset` it, like you do.

Answer (score 1):

Create link with the `$key`.

```
<a href="yourpage.php?key=<?php echo $key;?>">Delete</a>
```

then on that page

```
if (!empty($_GET['key'])){
    unset($_SESSION['name'][$_GET['key']]);
    unset($_SESSION['jenis'][$_GET['key']]);
    unset($_SESSION['merk'][$_GET['key']]);
    unset($_SESSION['katalog'][$_GET['key']]);
    unset($_SESSION['kemasan'][$_GET['key']]);
    unset($_SESSION['satuan'][$_GET['key']]);
    unset($_SESSION['satuanbsr'][$_GET['key']]);
    unset($_SESSION['kebutuhan'][$_GET['key']]);
    unset($_SESSION['jml_kebutuhan'][$_GET['key']]);
    unset($_SESSION['hps'][$_GET['key']]);
    unset($_SESSION['jml_harga'][$_GET['key']]);
}
```